# loading external text from .txt to a html file

Tags: javascript, html, text

I know how to load external text from a .txt file using

```
<div id="text"> <div>
```

and javascript

```
 $("#text").load("pathtofile/content.txt"); // element's id should be in string form
```

but can this be done between two < p > tags instead of inserting into a div? if so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the text from only a paragraph from the file, try this:
**HTML:**

```
<div id="tempDiv" style="display: none;"></div>
<p id="text"></p>
```

**JQuery:**

```
 var tempDiv = $('#tempDiv');
 tempDiv.load("pathToFile/content.txt");
 var html = tempDiv.find('#theParagraphId').html();
 $('#text').html(html);
```

Comment: Hi thanks, is it possible to specify a paragraph within the .txt file that it pulls from?

Comment: if you want to put that text into a <p> tag, so why not directly loading it into <p> tag.
why to use a separate <div> ?