# javascript to external .txt file

Tags: javascript, csv, text

I know how to point to an external javascript file using

```
    <script src="data.js"></script>
```

How will you point to an external text (.txt) or csv file? In the code below I am unable to point to test.txt.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>crossfilter + maps</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">

    <script src="chart.js"></script>

    <script src="setup2.js"></script>
    <script src="data.js"></script>
<script src="test.txt"></script>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544219/loading-external-text-from-txt-to-a-html-file

Comment: The file pointed to can have any extension. So `<script src="myscript.txt"></script>` is valid. Make sure it really contains a script.

Comment: You can load whatever you want in any loadable element, be it script, image, link or whatever, just the contents need to be supported by the element.

Comment: What does "point to" mean?

Comment: do you mean get the contents of a file inside DOM element?

Comment: so the script is just a bunch of comma separated values.        using <script src="myscript.txt"></script>                     gives me this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: can you post a sample of the script?

Comment: can you post a sample of the "script"? do you mean for it to run as javascript, or do you just want the csv?

Comment: @Todd, I just posted a sample code

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<div id='fileContainer'></div>
```

js

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var fileContainer = document.getElementById('fileContainer');
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.onload = function () {
                fileContainer.innerHTML = this.response;
            };

            xhr.open('GET', 'myFile.csv', true);
            xhr.send();
    }, false);
```

Comment: div in js is undefined. could you tell me how to define that?

Comment: sorry, it didn't. I edited the question above with my sample code.

Comment: can you specify exactly what you're trying to do, or what result you expect?