# Load values of a file at an html form

Tags: html

Is there any way to load the values of .txt file or .doc file and insert them at an html form as possible values? For example i have rooms 1-10 written at a txt file, and a form that i will need to scroll and check anyone of that rooms. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [loading external text from .txt to a html file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544219/loading-external-text-from-txt-to-a-html-file)

Answer (score 0):

In the past I did the following: one `iFrame` loads the txt file, with the `visibility: hidden;position: absolute` style. Its `onLoad` event triggers a Javascript function which can parse it. I usually use this reading function:

```
iframeObj = document.getElementById('put here the iFrame ID')
if (iframeObj != null)
{
    if (iframeObj.contentDocument)
    {
        txtfilecontent=iframeObj.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].innerHTML;
    }
    else if (iframeObj.contentWindow)
    {
        txtfilecontent=iframeObj.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
    }

    // Here you can use the txtfilecontent, which is a string
}
```

Usually I trigger a reload of the txt file in the end, but if you have to fill a form it is not recommended.

If you want to do that before loading the page, however, you should use a server side code, such as PHP and its `file_get_contents` function. The advantage of this approach is that you won't need to expose the txt file to the user, but it can stay hidden on the server.